# Python error : AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'len'

Tags: python

My code is very simple but I can't figure out why it is throwing this error ?

```
def median(numbers):
     newnumbers = numbers.sort()
     length = newnumbers.len()
     print length

median([4,6,1])
```

I searched online and also on SO and len() is correct way to get length of list. However, I keep getting error "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'len'"

What am I doing wrong here ?   Thanks !

Comment: First, sorting the list isn't going to change the length, so it seems unnecessary.

Comment: thanks. I posted only part of function I am writing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`numbers.sort()` works in place - it changes numbers, but returns `None`, so that's what `newnumbers` contain.
You should use `newnumbers = sorted(numbers)`, and this would solve the exception.

However, please note that sorting isn't required, as you're simply returning the length of the input list. So:

```
def median(numbers):
    print len(numbers)
```

would accomplish just the same. (and you're not returning the median)

Comment: I imagine the function is just incomplete, and he intends to return `numbers[len(numbers)/2]`.

Comment: That also, would not be the median if the list is of even length. I thought that pointing out additional errors is useful for him, like you did with len in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues here:

- The `sort()` method on lists just modifies the list, without returning a new one, so `newnumbers` is `None`.
- You should write `len(newnumbers)`, not `newnumbers.len()`.

Comment: That's *an* error, but not the root cause of the given error.

Comment: @chepner You're right -- I glossed over the question a bit. My bad!

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is not correct for finding length of a list.

The only change is `len(newnumbers)` which is required. There is no sole purpose of sorting which can be seen since you are not displaying the elements, the length will remain same regardless of sorting.